# Week number unique sortable integer id

Tags: php, datetime

My question is about programming philosophy, I give an example in PHP language but can be asked in any programming language:

- If I have to give an unique sortable integer ID to a day, I can use `'Ymd'` format
- If I have to give an unique sortable integer ID to a month, I can use `'Ym'` format
- If I have to give an unique sortable integer ID to a week, I **cannot** use `'YW'` format

Because of `2017-01-01` and `2017-12-31` will return the same week ID:

```
$date1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2017-01-01');
$date2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2017-12-31');
echo $date1->format('YW').' '.$date2->format('YW');
// returns 201752 201752
```

So I can use the first day ID of the week as unique sortable integer ID week but there is maybe a simpler way to solve it ? A better practice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `o` instead:

```
echo $date1->format('oW').' '.$date2->format('oW');
//201652 201752
```

> o ISO-8601 week-numbering year. This has the same value as Y, except that if the ISO week number (W) belongs to the previous or next year, that year is used instead. (added in PHP 5.1.0)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Exactly what I need, thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1):

You've to be aware when using **week** numbers with **years**. There is already a contribution note at php.net for this scenario **6** years back. Have a look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php#106974), Hope this will help you understand clearly :)

**Reason:**

`Y` is year from the date

`o` is ISO-8601 year number

`W` is ISO-8601 week number of year

```
$date1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2017-01-01');
$date2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2017-12-31');
echo $date1->format('YW').' '.$date2->format('YW');
echo PHP_EOL;
echo $date1->format('oW').' '.$date2->format('oW');
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/sMKAF

Comment: Thank you very much, I was not aware about `'o'` format.